# What do I need to develop an integration service to extract data from an Oracle DB to a SQL Server DB using Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssis, etl, visual-studio-2015

I have to develop an ETL to extract some data from an Oracle DB 11g to a SQL Server 2017 DB. I am pretty new at all this technology so I would like some advices. The strongest problem so far is to understand what I exactly need to perform this, as the more I read, the more confused I feel about all the tools I am supposed to install.

Here what I have so far:

- The SQL Server 2017 DB is on a server. I can access the DB through Microsoft SQL Manager. Also, I have access to the server itself through remote connection but no permission to install whatever I want. However, I guess I could ask for any installation if it was mandatory.
- The Oracle DB is on another server. I do not have access to the server itself. I have access to the DB through SQL Developer Tool. I access to the DB using EZ Connect, not a TNS.
- On my PC, I have the following tools installed:

  - Visual Studio 2015
  - Visual Studio extension Microsoft SQL data tool, in order to develop the SSIS
  - Visual Studio extension Oracle Developer Tools in order to connect to the Oracle DB through Visual Studio

I can already develop a SSIS and transfer some data from my PC to the SQL server DB. However, I am not able to connect to the Oracle DB through the SSIS.
I am pretty sure there are plenty of details that I am missing so I would be grateful to whoever that would give me any advice.

Comment: I have a few questions before I suggest to you. 1. Are you able to connect Oracle DB from SQL Database Server? 2. You need to extract tables from Oracle or analyzed data using SP? 3. If you need to sync tables what is size and number of tables? What is transaction ratio on the tables?

Comment: Surely stuff like this has been done before - why reinvent the wheel? This is not the place for this sort of "shopping list" question - try software recommendations on the SE network. Voting to close. Take a look at my profile for a few articles on how to answer questions here. p.s. welcome to the forum! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to synchronize data or extract database from one (source) to another (target) database, based on what is a business requirement.

If you need to extract raw data from Oracle to SQL Server, then you can use [Transactional Replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/publish/create-a-publication-from-an-oracle-database?view=sql-server-2017) which helps you to replicate tables and its data from Oracle to SQL Server.

ETL/SSIS can be used for the same purpose, but it's for more than just replication raw data. It also helps you to extract data from the source, analyze it, manipulate it and load to target.

To configure Transaction Replication for Oracle (as source):

1. Both databases should be accessible on respective servers.
2. Oracle Client should be installed on the SQL Database Server.
3. Configure listener on SQL DB server. The listener It is used while we configure replication.

Rest of the steps are mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/publish/create-a-publication-from-an-oracle-database?view=sql-server-2017).

Thanks